# Can't write time to database, only date. time gets ignored

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to insert date and time but only the date goes through. when I check the database the time is always 00:00

```
public void suspendPart(String partId, String startDate,
    String reasonCode, String endDate) throws DAOException {
    System.out.println("original date: "+startDate); //output: original date: 04/01/2013 08:42
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("p_id", Integer.parseInt(partId));
    Date dateTest = DAOUtils.parseDate(startDate, format);
    System.out.println("date after format " +dateTest); // output: date after format Fri Jan 04 08:42:00 GMT 2013
    params.put("p_start_date", dateTest);
    parts_package_add_part.execute(params);
}
```

I managed to make it work once but I don't know how. by the time I checked the database and saw a row with proper time, I had already messed with the code so it was lost.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: sp declaration

```
parts_package_add_part = SpringStoredProcedure
                .getStoredProcedureCompiled(getJdbcTemplate(), false,
                        "parts_package.add_part",
                        new SqlParameter("part_id", OracleTypes.NUMBER),
                        new SqlParameter("p_start_date", OracleTypes.DATE));
```

Edit: I can't change the database. well not easily at least. I would need to get PLSQL developer to do it and that will take days

Comment: What is the datatype you are using in database? Timestamp?

Comment: @ShashankKadne It's a Date type

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a simular problem. My solution was to use TIMESTAMP as oracle data type in the database table and the java.sql.Timestamp class in java. This matched fine...

Answer (score 2):

Using Timestamp could help. What is the datatype used to store your date in db? May be it is a Date type. If you convert that to Timestame/DateTime it could help.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try using timestamp datatype in your database table and also from your java code use java.sql.Timestamp it will store data and time both for you 
Thanks